# A whole storm of unknown errors while rebooting my Sharepoint Server 2010?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

Okay, these are the errors I can't backtrace at all. So I was hoping you had any idea.

When I recently rebooted my server (The server is a home computer, and just runs Windows 7 as a development machine) with Sharepoint 2010, a whole list of problems occurred.

The major error was that when I deployed my Visual Studio 2010 project, it couldn't activate my Feature. This happens more often, because I sometimes mess up in my Feature Activation event handler. But, when that happens, I can access the site, and debug the error while activating the feature manually.

However, this time, things were different. My site didn't even want to start up? So I checked IIS Manager, and it said that the site was stopped. Manually starting it resulted in the following error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)
```

I have no clue what that could mean? What file? The web.config? I really don't know.

But I saw that the Sharepoint Central Administration was running, so I decided to check there. However, this resulted in even more errors, well, there was one, but it really frightened me:

```
Cannot connect to the configuration database.
```

So, not only my Web server is having errors, but also my database server. Time to check the event logs is what I thought.

And there I'm a bit stunned. There are so many errors, I don't even know where to start. I'm just going to copy the ones which I think are important.

> Unknown SQL Exception -1 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Sharepoint Foundation seems to give me that one.

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix http://*:80/ for site 908852174. The site has been disabled. The data field contains the error number.

IIS-W3SVC seems to give me that one.

I.. really have no clue what could be the case. Since I cannot acces Central Administration, I can't check for any health issues either.

Anyone has even the slightest idea? I didn't do anything funny I believe. I was thinking that it could've been the updates that were installed, but the only updates installed were:

> Security Update for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package (KB973923)
>
> Definition Update for Microsoft Security Essentials - KB972696 (Definition 1.93.855.0)
>
> Definition Update for Microsoft Security Essentials - KB972696 (Definition 1.93.1040.0)
>
> Definition Update for Microsoft Security Essentials - KB972696 (Definition 1.93.1148.0)

So, it really couldn't have been that. I'm out of ideas, and I really would like to solve this.

Thanks,

Mats

EDIT: Okay, manually started up the SQL Service, and now Central Administration works. But, The Health reporting site started scaring me. There's a list of 8 items requiring my attention.

> NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, the account used for the SharePoint timer service and the central administration site, is highly privileged and should not be used for any other services on any machines in the server farm.  The following services were found to use this account: SharePoint - 80 (Application Pool)
> SPUserCodeV4(Windows Service)
> OSearch14(Windows Service)
> Web Analytics Data Processing Service(Windows Service)

> All required products must be installed on all servers in the farm, and all products should have the same patching and upgrade level across the farm.
> Upgrade is required on server MATS-PC. Without the upgrade, the server is not in a supported state.

> The following databases have versions that are older than the current SharePoint software, but are within the backwards compatible range:
> SharePoint_Config_c5681991-3bec-45b3-9376-ea8c19c51b6a,
> SharePoint_AdminContent_39d0c8e9-214e-42b9-909e-ffbe4147208b,
> WSS_Content,
> WSS_Search_MATS-PC,
> WSS_Logging.

Those seemed to be the most relevant. Hm. I have no clue? Especially about the upgrading? I didn't upgrade anything recently.

Comment: Hm. It seemed that the SHAREPOINT SQL Server service didn't start up. So, manually starting it seemed to do the trick for the Central Administration. And now, there are some 'critical health issues'. Let me edit up my post with them.

Comment: Yeah, it was created from scratch. I installed Windows 7, and then Sharepoint 2010. Nothing funny, really.

Comment: Eh. I ran that command. And it did run successfully. It's just that, it didn't seem to help? I mean, my Sharepoint site on 80 still doesn't seem to work. And doesn't seem to want to run. Gah. I really don't have the time to reinstall this all. There has to be a better solution! Or at least a source for the problem.

Comment: Well, the 80 site doesn't even want to run in IIS. So, when I access it it just gives me the 'page not found' error. And no, no new messages in the Health Analyzer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Especially about the upgrading? I didn't upgrade anything recently.**

This sounds a lot like a Microsoft Update.  Service packs for SQL Server come through Microsoft Update, and if you applied those without checking carefully, some of them produce similar symptoms to what you're describing.  SQL Server can take longer to start up, and when that happens, sometimes antivirus software grabs the MDF/LDF files for scanning.  That will cause the databases to be unavailable, and other services will then fail on startup.

When you started SQL manually, things started working again, but now you've got version dependency problems.  You're lucky SQL even starts, though - I've had clients with issues where SQL won't start after careless SP applications if they had changed the SA login, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you got while doing the reboot where just because the SQL Service did not startup. No database = no SharePoint. This happens to me all the time.

The other messages in Central Administration are nothing to do with your SQL startup and chances are they have been there for some time.

As any other developer on a single box hosting SharePoint, you have permissioned stuff with a single powerful account. Central Admin now detects this and gives you the warning.

It looks like the SharePoint versions of one or more of your server databases are out of sync with the version of 2010? Not exactly sure how it got into this state, but for a dev box I would not be completely stressed. An upgrade to the new service pack hopefully would sort this out.